# GITHUB: How to convert forked repository that was turned standalone back t a fork

Tags: git, github, repository, fork

I have a github fork that was turned standalone after the main repository changed from private to public.

According to [github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/), if a private repository is made public, each of its private forks is turned into a standalone private repository and becomes the parent of its own new repository network. The documentation advises that such a repository should either be made public or upgraded.

I have so far changed my repo to public but it is still standalone. Is there a way to connect it back to main repo? There are some pull requests I had submitted while still private and I'd like to follow up with extra updates.

Comment: The "what is this a fork of" is a github only feature, which does not have anything to do with git itself.  So create a new fork that is as you want and - as they have the same git information - pull in the information from your old fork that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork again, add the forked repository as remote and then `git push --all --force` from your local clone of your "unforked" repo.